# Is there any way to show my DataProvider values in TestNG report summary?

Tags: java, selenium, testng, dataprovider, testng-dataprovider

Basically, I am running my automation tests on LambdaTest Selenium Grid on multiple configurations. I have 7 test class files added in my testng test suite. I have passed my configurations such as browser, browser version, OS and resolution in my `DataProvider` class. Each test would run on all configurations passed in `DataProvider` class. However, I am not able to get those configuration values in the summary part of testng emailable-report.

What I want is to have `DataProvider` class file--configuration values in the summary part of testng emailable-report which would help me getting that on which configuration each test has passed or failed.

As of now, my testng report looks like this: https://ibb.co/5TbDdGw

On the top it shows 7 test cases added in 7 different class file.

```
package com.mydataprovider;

import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

public class MyDataProvider {

@DataProvider
public Object[][] realTimeConfiguration() {
    return new Object[][] { 

        new Object[] {"chrome", "chrome76","win10","1280x1024" },
        new Object[] {"chrome", "chrome75","win10","1280x1024" },
        new Object[] {"chrome", "chrome74","win10","1280x1024" },
        new Object[] {"chrome", "chrome73","win10","1280x1024" },
        new Object[] {"chrome", "chrome72","win10","1280x1024" },


        new Object[] {"firefox", "firefox68","win10","1280x1024" },
        new Object[] {"firefox", "firefox67","win10","1280x1024" },
        new Object[] {"firefox", "firefox66","win10","1280x1024" },
        new Object[] {"firefox", "firefox65","win10","1280x1024" },
        new Object[] {"firefox", "firefox64","win10","1280x1024" },

        };
    }
}
```

This is my `DataProvider` class which includes the configuration.
In the report screenshot shared, it shows that all test methods ran on all 10 configuration mentioned in the `DataProvider`. However, it doesn't show the configuration in the report summary that on which configuration my each test ran.

Please help generating a report which includes `DataProvider` values in the summary of testng report.

Answer (score 0):

You can add them to the description of the tests.

```
@Test(dataProviderClass = DataProviderClass.class, dataProvider = "dataProviderMethod")
public void testMethod(String param1, String param2, String param3, String param4) {
    ITestResult result = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
    result.getMethod().setDescription(param1 + " " + param2 + " " + param3 + " " + param4);
}
```

Comment: Hi Prakash, thanks for the reply. But it doesn't helped with my scenario. The code you have shared generates the same testng emailable-report as it was generating before. Basically, I want my parameters passed from DataProvider class to be mentioned in the "method" column of testng report. Here is the screenshot for your reference:   https://ibb.co/q0NqNqV       Looking forward to hear from you again. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your dataProvider against the code written against article, where you have posted your comment-
https://www.swtestacademy.com/change-test-name-testng-dataprovider/

I got the below result-

```
PASSED: testRenaming_chrome76("chrome", "chrome76", "win10", "1280x1024")
PASSED: testRenaming_chrome75("chrome", "chrome75", "win10", "1280x1024")
PASSED: testRenaming_chrome74("chrome", "chrome74", "win10", "1280x1024")
PASSED: testRenaming_chrome73("chrome", "chrome73", "win10", "1280x1024")
PASSED: testRenaming_chrome72("chrome", "chrome72", "win10", "1280x1024")
PASSED: testRenaming_firefox68("firefox", "firefox68", "win10", "1280x1024")
PASSED: testRenaming_firefox67("firefox", "firefox67", "win10", "1280x1024")
PASSED: testRenaming_firefox66("firefox", "firefox66", "win10", "1280x1024")
PASSED: testRenaming_firefox65("firefox", "firefox65", "win10", "1280x1024")
PASSED: testRenaming_firefox64("firefox", "firefox64", "win10", "1280x1024")
```

- I have changed to testData[1] in BeforeMethod for printing browser versions in testName, also increased the params in Test to 4 instead of 1.